# PowerShell SendKeys to InternetExplorer ComObject

Tags: shell, powershell, sendkeys

Here's one method I found which brings the IE ComObject window to the foreground and uses SendKeys.

**How would I send a sequence of key presses using this method?**

```psh
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.navigate("www.google.com")
do {sleep 1} until (-not ($ie.Busy))
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type @"
 using System;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 public class StartActivateProgramClass {
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
 public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
 }
"@
$hWnd = $ie.HWND
$ie.Visible = $true
[void] [StartActivateProgramClass]::SetForegroundWindow($hWnd)
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("a 2")
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to load the windows form assembly to use SendKeys. 
here is an example

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")

$ie=new-object -com "internetexplorer.application"
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("http://someURI")

#waiting for my form 
while( ($ie.document.body.getElementsbytagname("input") |?{$_.type -eq 'file'}) -eq $null){
        start-sleep -milliseconds 100
    }
# give the focus to ie
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("internet explorer")

#send keys 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{TAB}");   
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait(" ");   
start-sleep 1
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait($file);         
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{TAB}");
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{ENTER}");
```

I tried this myself to automate IE in order to make some performance tests, but SendKeys is not a safe way to do this, imagine an application steals the focus and then all the keys are send to this app instead of IE. Using Selenium project would be the way to go I think

Comment: I wish it was that easy, IE is always open already so `AppActivate` likely will focus on the wrong instance.  This is why in my example `MakeTopMost` acts on the HWND of the newly created IE ComObject.  It doesn't help I'm still a novice scripter.  Plus, [this article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/10/provide-input-to-applications-with-powershell.aspx) mentions `LoadWithPartialName` is obsolete and to use `Add-Type` instead.  Call me confused!

Comment: You said you already have a working method to give the focus to your IE instance, so should be able to interract with it via sendkeys .

Comment: Yes, `$app = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $signature -Name Win32Window -Namespace ScriptFanatic.WinAPI -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms -Using System.Windows.Forms -PassThru` however that's a result from http://poshcode.org/1837 and I'm beyond lost trying to work in the `SendKeys` method.

Comment: another option may be to use the [wasp](https://wasp.codeplex.com/) module from codeplex.

Comment: I've seen WASP but want to avoid using external dependancies.  I'm updating the question with some more borrowed code.

Comment: Strange, when I swap in our internal ticket system's site, I cannot get the `SendKeys` to actually send the keys.  Even worse when the page is displayed, the first drop down field is focused.  This does not happen when I launch the page as a ComObject and try sending keys to it.

Comment: Si Just focus an input field  :)

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to see if .NET sendkey methods would click a button with a script I wrote to automatically log me into a https: website.(Eventually I will schedule with task scheduler and have it automate at a certain time everyday). I used the {Enter} send key from the .NET Assembly. It worked for me so I decided to share in hopes it would help someone.

You may have to inspect your html document to see what specific type the TagName is and edit accordingly.

$IE=new-object -com Internetexplorer.application

```
$IE.navigate2("https://Yourwebsite.com")
$IE.visible=$true
do { sleep 15 }
while ( $IE.busy )

$Link=@($IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input.")) | where-object {$_.type     -eq "submit"}
$click=$Link.[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{ENTER}");
$click
```

**** You have to add the .NET namespace in your Powershell script to use the namespace or it will give you and error ****

Ex. [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")