# Call onkeyup="lookup(this.value, event) function while doing automation

Tags: powershell, automation, scripting

I am trying to perform IE automation using PowerShell. While automating some manual task using IE object, 
I am able to navigate to the website and enter value in text box, but the submit button is not available on website.
Getting output after clicking enter manually on ie page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell SendKeys to InternetExplorer ComObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531022/powershell-sendkeys-to-internetexplorer-comobject)

Comment: Thanks, Theo, it's working

Comment: Hi Theo, Your suggested method is working fine but as when I switched to other work it now working. Actually while running this script I am unable to do other work. Please help me get out it.