# IE Automation with Powershell send ENTER Key

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, automation, servicenow

I am doing an IE Automation with ServiceNow where there is an option to fill the search data but there is no search button available to use the CLICK method. So I am looking for the method to enter key like {ENTER} or {~} once I filled the search data. But I am in a middle stage of PowerShell scripting and not sure how to use that.

If someone could help me with the method that would be greatly appreciate.

```
$IE = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.application
$IE.FullScreen = $false
$IE.Visible = $true
$IE.Navigate($ServiceNowURL)

While ($IE.Busy -eq $true)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
}

$Enter = Read-Host 'To continue press ENTER'

#Enter
$Search = $IE.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByTagName('input') | ? {$_.id -eq 'sysparm_search'}
$EnterValue = $Search.value() = $TicketNumber
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531022/powershell-sendkeys-to-internetexplorer-comobject - maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to active IE window and bring it to front using `AppActivate`, then set focus to the search area using `focus()`. After that, you can send **Enter** key using `SendKeys`.

I use https://www.google.com to search as an example and you can refer to my code sample below. I test it and it works well:

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("'Microsoft.VisualBasic")

$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible=$true
$ie.Navigate("https://www.google.com") #change it to your own url
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4 -or $ie.Busy) {Start-Sleep -m 100}
$search=$ie.Document.getElementsByName("q")[0] #change it to your own selector
$search.value="PowerShell" #change it to your own search value

Sleep 5
$ieProc = Get-Process | ? { $_.MainWindowHandle -eq $ie.HWND }
[Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate($ieProc.Id) 
$search.focus() 
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::Sendwait("{ENTER}");
```